# Maybe its Mysql syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Hello all well i dont know my error cleary here If i Open my site i get on the left side Bed Sql Syntax here is my code

```
  <?php

$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="l2jgs";  //the name of the database
$chandle = mysqli_connect("localhost", $dbuser, $dbpass) 
    or die("Connection Failure to Database");
mysqli_select_db($chandle, "l2jgs");
$sql="insert characters.char_name,characters.pvpkills,char_templates.ClassName,characters.online from characters,char_templates where characters.classid=char_templates.Classid order by characters.pvpkills DESC LIMIT "."NumberOfResults";
echo"<html><head></head><body bgcolor='#000000' style='color:rgb(200,200,200)'>";
echo "<table  border='2' align=center width=500>";
echo "<tr><th>Nr.</th><th>Name</th><th>Pvp Kills</th><th>Main class</th><th>Status</th></tr>\n";
$nr=1;
if ($result=mysqli_query($chandle,$sql)or die("Bed Sql syntax")) {
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
     echo "<tr><td align=center>".$nr."</td>";
     $nr++;
   echo "<td align=center>".$row[0]."</td>";
   echo "<td align=center>".$row[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td align=center>".$row[2]."</td>";
        if($row[3])
{echo "<td align=center style='color:rgb(0,255,0)'>Online</td></tr>\n"; }
  else{echo "<td align=center style='color:rgb(255,0,0)'>Offline</td></tr>\n";}
  }
} else {
  echo "<!-- SQL Error ".mysql_error()." -->";
}
echo "</table></body></html>";


?>
```

Sorry if its already but I didnt saw any post that fits my question 
Thank you all :)

Comment: check your query. it's seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Your query seems to be a `SELECT`. So instead of `INSERT`, put `$sql="select characters.char_name, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query syntax is incorrect.

Seeing the echos below your query, you want to use `SELECT` and not `INSERT`.

```
$sql="SELECT characters.char_name,characters.pvpkills,
      char_templates.ClassName,characters.online 
FROM characters,char_templates 
WHERE characters.classid=char_templates.Classid 
ORDER BY characters.pvpkills 
DESC LIMIT "."NumberOfResults"; // <= unclear
```

**Sidenote:** `NumberOfResults` that isn't correct and is treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). Having used error reporting, that would have triggered an `Undefined constant NumberOfResults` notice. That should either be a number or a pre-defined variable. You may have meant to use `$NumberOfResults` and defined before the query, such as `$NumberOfResults = 10;` for example.

Please consult the manual for SELECT:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

and the manual for INSERT:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Having used `or die(mysqli_error($chandle))` to `mysqli_query()` instead of
`or die("Bed Sql syntax")`  would have signaled the real error as to why your query failed.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement looks off to me:

```
INSERT characters.char_name, 
         characters.pvpkills, 
         char_templates.classname, 
         characters.online 
FROM     characters, 
         char_templates 
WHERE    characters.classid=char_templates.classid 
ORDER BY characters.pvpkills DESC limit numberofresults
```

Usually that would be INSERT FIELDS INTO TABLE WHERE CRITERIA, and you shouldn't worry about the ORDER BY on an insert, just when you query the data back out.  Maybe:

```
INSERT characters.char_name, 
         characters.pvpkills, 
         char_templates.classname, 
         characters.online 
INTO     characters, 
         char_templates 
WHERE    characters.classid=char_templates.classid
```

OR:

```
SELECT characters.char_name, 
         characters.pvpkills, 
         char_templates.classname, 
         characters.online 
FROM   characters, 
         char_templates 
WHERE    characters.classid=char_templates.classid 
ORDER BY characters.pvpkills
DESC LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your sql (with problems):

```
insert  
    characters.char_name,  
    characters.pvpkills,  
    char_templates.ClassName,  
    characters.online  
from  
    characters,  
    char_templates  
where  
    characters.classid = char_templates.Classid  
order by  
    characters.pvpkills  
DESC LIMIT NumberOfResults;
```

1) You want to `select` not `insert`.
2) NumberOfResults must be a number, not a string. I didn't see a variable with the name 'NumberOfResults', so maybe you just want to make it a specific value, maybe 100?
3) Its better to use aliases for your tables, not the full table name.
4) Use the php multiline strings, its much easier to read sql queries this way.

Fixed version, ready for copy-paste:

```
$sql = <<< SQL  
    SELECT  
        char.char_name,  
        char.pvpkills,  
        ct.ClassName,  
        char.online  
    FROM  
        characters char,  
        char_templates ct  
    WHERE  
        char.classid = ct.Classid  
    ORDER BY  
        char.pvpkills DESC  
    LIMIT 100;  
SQL;
```